# Function that expects u16 return type errors, mismatched types even though I am using return to get values early out of function

Tags: rust, compiler-errors

I am getting an error

> mismatched types error, expected u16, found ()

from this function (code below) and I can't seem to find why because it is guaranteed to return u16 or am I missing something?

`assign_value` is a method of my struct and type `self.fields` is `Vec<Vec<u16>>`.

```
    pub fn assign_value(&self, input: u16) -> u16 {
        for (row, vector) in self.fields.iter().enumerate() {
            for (column, value) in self.fields[row].iter().enumerate() {
                if *value == 0 {
                    return input;
                } else {
                    return *value;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if `self.fields` is empty? In this case, the loop won't be executed at all. What will be returned?

In general, all loop kinds except `loop` without `break` cannot affect whether the function will return, because they may not run.

Comment: Thanks that explains it! Also is there a way to bypass this without adding additional code because my code already makes it so that self.fields is never empty. I guess adding just u16 at the end of the function would work?

Comment: @Newb Then just return a dummy value, say 0. You can also `panic!()` but this will be less efficient (bigger code size), OTOH this will give you more safety (offensive programming, panic if your invariants were broken). There is no way to bypass the check completely without `unsafe` and there's really no reason to use `unsafe` here. You can document that this part of the code is unreachable. I would panic with `unreachable!()`.

Comment: Great unreachable!() seems like the best thing to do, thanks again.